# How can I display multiple render calls on webpage?

Tags: python, django, rendering

I'm getting started with the Django framework but can't figure out how to have multiple render calls from the views python file appear on my webpage.

Within the url python file, I tried adding a new path and calling the function similar to how I did for the createPunnettSquare (which worked fine). My project ran fine but I was expecting the title to say 'punnett square' but only 'punnett' appears.

Thanks in advance for any help as this is my first post. If more information is needed I can defintely provide it.

[webpage output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5YAF.png)

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
# request -> response
# request handler


def createPunnettSquare(request):
    genotype1 = "Aa"
    genotype2 = "Bb"
    l_offsprings = []
    punnett_square = [[""]*len(genotype1) for i in range(len(genotype2))]

    for i in range(len(genotype1)):
        for j in range(len(genotype2)):
            p_offspring = fill_array(request, j, i, genotype1, genotype2)
            l_offsprings.append(p_offspring)
    dy_offsprings = {"offsprings": l_offsprings}
    return render(request, 'hello.html', dy_offsprings)

def fill_array(request, j, i, genotype1, genotype2):
    offspring = genotype1[j] + genotype2[i]
    if offspring[0].isupper() == False:
        offspring = offspring[::-1]
    return offspring

def sayhi(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {"name": "square"})
```

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

# URL configuration module (every app can have its own module)
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.createPunnettSquare),
    path('', views.sayhi)
]
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <style>
        .header1{
        text-align: center;
        }
        .header2{
        text-align: center;
        }
        .header3{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .monohybrid{
        margin: 20px auto;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        background-color:#fff;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
        grid-row: auto auto;
        grid-column-gap: 20px;
        grid-row-gap: 20px;
        }
        .mBox{
        background-color:#3a3232;
        padding:20px;
        border-radius:10px;
        color:#fff;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
        font-size:40px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h1 class="header1"> Punnett {{ name }} </h1>
        <h2 class="header2"> Monohybrid Crosses</h2>
        <!-- <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="fname">P1 Genotype: </label>
            <input type="text" id="p1geno" name="p1geno"><br><br>
            <label for="lname">P2 Genotype: </label>
            <input type="text" id="p2geno" name="p2geno"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form> -->
        <div class="monohybrid">
            {% for i in offsprings %}
            <div class="mBox">{{ i }} </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of [`render()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is the context variable where you provide all the variables which you want to use in the template. So put everything there in the first view function:

```
context = {
    "offsprings": l_offsprings,
    "name": "square",
}
return render(request, 'hello.html', context)
```